# CakePHP 2.x: call virtual fields over associated model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, model-associations

i have the Model `ExternalShare`, which *hasOne* `SfileVersion`. And a third Model `Sfile`, which *hasMany* `SfileVersion`.

In *SfileVersion* i have in $virtualFields the following code:

```
class SfileVersion extends AppModel {    
    public $virtualFields = array(
            'active' => 'SfileVersion.is_active',
            'externalShare' => 'ExternalShare.id'
    );
    [...]
}
```

AppModel looks like the following code, so, *Containable* is available everywhere:

```
class AppModel extends Model {
    public $recursive = -1;
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

Now i try to call the `find('all')` method in `SfileController`, to get data from `Sfile` and `SfileVersion`:

```
class SfilesController extends AppController {    
    public function index() {
        $this->Sfile->recursive = 0;
        $this->Sfile->contain('SfileVersion');
        $allSfiles = $this->Sfile->find('all');
    }
    [...]
}
```

Now i get the follwing error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ExternalShare.id' in 'field list'
```

In the CookBook (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#limitations-of-virtualfields), here is

> A common workaround for this implementation issue is to copy
>   virtualFields from one model to another at runtime when you need to
>   access them

, which i tried, by adding the following lines in front of the `find('all')`:

```
$this->Sfile->virtualFields['externalShare'] = $this->Sfile->SfileVersion->virtualFields['externalShare'];
```

But i get still the same error. I didnt directly understand, what the workaround is doing. Also, my virtual fields may not the problem (active seems to work), just the special one, which points to an other (third) Model association (`ExternalShare.id`). Does someone have an idea or solution? Thank you very much!

Comment: If ExternalShare hasOne SfileVersion, then a relationship exists which is  equivalent to `ExternalShare.id =  SfileVersion.ExternalShare_id` The point is that your SfileVersion's table has a column that stores the primary key of the ExternalShare's table. Use that that column in your virtual field definition, not ExternalShare.id.

Comment: Wow, you are right, i overlooked that. So easy but i didn`t see it in hours... that was the solution, thank you very much @AgRizzo! - How i can set the option that your anwser is the solution to my question?

Comment: @Zeussi, you just write it in an answer and accept it